# MySQL Trigger Won't Fire After Insert From Wordpress Endpoint

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all high scores except the top 10.

My query works fine as a query in PHPMysql, but when I try to use it in a trigger, it doesn't fire.

If anyone has a suggestion or needs additional information, please let me know. Thanks.

```
//The query
DELETE FROM ONEGameleaderboard WHERE _id Not IN
 (SELECT * FROM (SELECT _id FROM ONEGameleaderboard ORDER BY Score DESC , Date ASC LIMIT 10)  as t)

//The Trigger insert query
CREATE TRIGGER `ONEGameleaderboardTop10Limit` AFTER INSERT ON `ONEGameleaderboard`
 FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM ONEGameleaderboard WHERE _id Not IN
 (SELECT * FROM (SELECT _id FROM ONEGameleaderboard ORDER BY Score DESC , Date ASC LIMIT 10)  as t)

//The insert code form the WordPress endpoint (Which inserts the data just fine)
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

   $parameters = $request->get_json_params();

 if($request['id'] == 1)
    {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ONEGameleaderboard (Date, Name, Score) VALUES ('$parameters[Date]', '$parameters[Name]', '$parameters[Score]')";
  }
elseif($request['id'] == 2)
    {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO TWOGameleaderboard (Date, Name, Score) VALUES ('$parameters[Date]', '$parameters[Name]', '$parameters[Score]')";
  }
 elseif($request['id'] == 3)
    {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO THREEGameleaderboard (Date, Name, Score) VALUES ('$parameters[Date]', '$parameters[Name]', '$parameters[Score]')";
  }
  else
    {       
            $message = 'No Leaderboard Table for this Index';
            return new WP_ERROR('no_data', $message, array('status' => 404));
    }


 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
} 

$conn->close();
```

Comment: "select * from" in the delete query seems redundant.

Comment: This is a trigger *after* insert. If the inserted record does not appear in the first 10 rows as sorted by the inner query, it will be deleted again (if you have >=10 records). so you are probably deleting it after it's being inserted. You may check that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The select* was necessary because Mysql says it doesn't allow Limit in a subquery. I check to see if the highscore is high enough BEFORE I call the URL, but if it somehow slips by, this trigger should delete it if it's too low. My problem is that I have more than 10 records and the trigger isn't deleting them.